# SQL Server : passing nullable parameters to a stored procedure with dynamic query

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, dynamic

I'm having a bit of trouble passing a nullable parameter to a stored procedure that uses dynamic queries to run through a table.

What I need to be able to do is pass null to all parameters that are nullable. If I take this code out of dynamic SQL it works fine.

The code:

```
ALTER proc [dbo].[TEST_spExtractNL_Dynamic]
    @StartDate date,
    @Company nvarchar(1) = null,
    @Location1 nvarchar(1) = null,
    @Location2 nvarchar(1) = null,
    @Department nvarchar(1) = null,
    @P1 nvarchar(1) = null,
    @P2 nvarchar(1) = null,
    @P3 nvarchar(1) = null,
    @P4 nvarchar(1) = null,
    @P5 nvarchar(1) = null,
    @P6 nvarchar(1) = null,
    @P7 nvarchar(1) = null,
    @P8 nvarchar(1) = null
as
begin
    Create table #TempTable
    (
        [Type] [float] NOT NULL,
        [Description] [nvarchar](100) NOT NULL
    )

    DECLARE @DynamicQuery_CurrentActual AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
    SET @DynamicQuery_CurrentActual = N'SELECT
                                           SUM([Budget]) * -1 as [Type],
                                           ''Current Actual'' as  [Description]
                                        FROM [TS_Group_Reports].[dbo].[SDCG_FINREP_DataDump]
                                        WHERE
    [Date] BETWEEN ''' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(@StartDate),MONTH(@StartDate),1), 101) + ''' AND ''' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),EOMONTH(@StartDate), 101) + '''
    AND
    (''' + @Company + ''' IS NULL OR (SUBSTRING(CAST([Accont] as nvarchar(12)),1,1) = ''' + @Company + '''))
    AND
    (''' + @Location1 + ''' IS NULL OR (SUBSTRING(CAST([Accont] as nvarchar(12)),2,1) = ''' + @Location1 + '''))
    AND
    (''' + @Location2 + ''' IS NULL OR (SUBSTRING(CAST([Accont] as nvarchar(12)),3,1) = ''' + @Location2 + '''))
    AND
    (''' + @Department + ''' IS NULL OR (SUBSTRING(CAST([Accont] as nvarchar(12)),4,1) = ''' + @Department + '''))

    AND
    (''' + @P1 + ''' IS NULL OR (SUBSTRING(CAST([Accont] as nvarchar(12)),5,1) = ''' + @P1 + '''))
    AND
    (''' + @P2 + ''' IS NULL OR (SUBSTRING(CAST([Accont] as nvarchar(12)),6,1) = ''' + @P2 + '''))
    AND
    (''' + @P3 + ''' IS NULL OR (SUBSTRING(CAST([Accont] as nvarchar(12)),7,1) = ''' + @P3 + '''))
    AND
    (''' + @P4 + ''' IS NULL OR (SUBSTRING(CAST([Accont] as nvarchar(12)),8,1) = ''' + @P4 + '''))
    AND
    (''' + @P5 + ''' IS NULL OR (SUBSTRING(CAST([Accont] as nvarchar(12)),9,1) = ''' + @P5 + '''))
    AND
    (''' + @P6 + ''' IS NULL OR (SUBSTRING(CAST([Accont] as nvarchar(12)),10,1) = ''' + @P6 + '''))
    AND
    (''' + @P7 + ''' IS NULL OR (SUBSTRING(CAST([Accont] as nvarchar(12)),11,1) = ''' + @P7 + '''))
    AND
    (''' + @P8 + ''' IS NULL OR (SUBSTRING(CAST([Accont] as nvarchar(12)),12,1) = ''' + @P8 + '''))
    AND
    [Type] like ''_A'''

DECLARE @DynamicQuery_CurrentBudget AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
SET @DynamicQuery_CurrentBudget =
N'SELECT
    sum([Budget]) * -1 as [Type]
    ,''Current Budget'' as [Description]
FROM [TS_Group_Reports].[dbo].[SDCG_FINREP_DataDump]
WHERE
    [Date] BETWEEN ''' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(@StartDate),MONTH(@StartDate),1), 101) + ''' AND ''' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),EOMONTH(@StartDate), 101) + '''
    AND
    (''' + @Company + ''' IS NULL OR (SUBSTRING(CAST([Accont] as nvarchar(12)),1,1) = ''' + @Company + '''))
    AND
    (''' + @Location1 + ''' IS NULL OR (SUBSTRING(CAST([Accont] as nvarchar(12)),2,1) = ''' + @Location1 + '''))
    AND
    (''' + @Location2 + ''' IS NULL OR (SUBSTRING(CAST([Accont] as nvarchar(12)),3,1) = ''' + @Location2 + '''))
    AND
    (''' + @Department + ''' IS NULL OR (SUBSTRING(CAST([Accont] as nvarchar(12)),4,1) = ''' + @Department + '''))

    AND
    (''' + @P1 + ''' IS NULL OR (SUBSTRING(CAST([Accont] as nvarchar(12)),5,1) = ''' + @P1 + '''))
    AND
    (''' + @P2 + ''' IS NULL OR (SUBSTRING(CAST([Accont] as nvarchar(12)),6,1) = ''' + @P2 + '''))
    AND
    (''' + @P3 + ''' IS NULL OR (SUBSTRING(CAST([Accont] as nvarchar(12)),7,1) = ''' + @P3 + '''))
    AND
    (''' + @P4 + ''' IS NULL OR (SUBSTRING(CAST([Accont] as nvarchar(12)),8,1) = ''' + @P4 + '''))
    AND
    (''' + @P5 + ''' IS NULL OR (SUBSTRING(CAST([Accont] as nvarchar(12)),9,1) = ''' + @P5 + '''))
    AND
    (''' + @P6 + ''' IS NULL OR (SUBSTRING(CAST([Accont] as nvarchar(12)),10,1) = ''' + @P6 + '''))
    AND
    (''' + @P7 + ''' IS NULL OR (SUBSTRING(CAST([Accont] as nvarchar(12)),11,1) = ''' + @P7 + '''))
    AND
    (''' + @P8 + ''' IS NULL OR (SUBSTRING(CAST([Accont] as nvarchar(12)),12,1) = ''' + @P8 + '''))
    AND
    [Type] like ''_B'''

    insert into #TempTable
       EXEC sp_executesql @DynamicQuery_CurrentActual

    insert into #TempTable
       EXEC sp_executesql @DynamicQuery_CurrentBudget

    select * 
    from #TempTable
END
```

The table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[SDCG_FINREP_DataDump]
(
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Accont] [bigint] NOT NULL,
    [Description] [nvarchar](100) NOT NULL,
    [Date] [date] NOT NULL,
    [Budget] [float] NOT NULL,
    [Type] [nvarchar](5) NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT [PK_SDCG_FINREP_DataDump] 
       PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED
 ) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Comment: You are using `sp_executesql`.  Now, use it correctly and pass the values in as *parameters* rather than exposing the query to SQL injection and potential syntax errors.

Comment: The issue looks like you're trying to check whether 'NULL' (as a string) is null (it isn't). You could do something like `''' + ISNULL(@var, '') + ''' = ''''` or something like that. Or what Gordon said with properly using parameters.

Comment: you should use the RECOMPILE option for this Stored Procedure, https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ie/library/ms190439.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using `sp_executesql` with parameters. Here i only demonstrate one of the parameter `@Company` only

```
SET @DynamicQuery_CurrentBudget =
N'SELECT
    sum([Budget]) * -1 as [Type]
    ,''Current Budget'' as [Description]
FROM [TS_Group_Reports].[dbo].[SDCG_FINREP_DataDump]
WHERE
    [Date] BETWEEN ''' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(@StartDate),MONTH(@StartDate),1), 101) + ''' AND ''' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),EOMONTH(@StartDate), 101) + '''
    AND
    ('@Company IS NULL OR (SUBSTRING(CAST([Accont] as nvarchar(12)),1,1) =  @Company))
```

and then use sp_executesql with parameters

```
EXEC sp_executesql @DynamicQuery_CurrentActual, N'@Company nvarchar(1)', @Company
```